# Mixing colors in Photoshop

Tags: color

Is there a way to mix colors in Photoshop. For instance, here is what I want to do.

[image: Colors]

But here is what I get when using Multiply blending mode as suggested elsewhere on the internet. [image]

I've also tried the opacity method, but I'm trying to emulate smoke so the opacity is already lower and so doesn't really work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Red layer on top set to "Lighten"
2. Blue layer under that
3. Duplicate of Red layer on bottom, set to "Normal"
4. Link both red layers

Example

[image]

If you want a darker purple fill the top red shape a darker red

[image]